# Can something be described as having particular advantages, without (explicit or implied) comparison to something else which lacks these?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, comparisons

## Context

During class in my current university course we are often asked to give advantages and disadvantages of certain scientific methods.

When asked the question *"What are the advantages of X?"*, I sought clarification: *"In comparison to what?"*

I thought this was a reasonable question, and still do, as there were multiple other methods with against which X could be compared, each with different attributes.

However my teacher (a fluent but non-native english speaker) disagreed, essentially asserting that advantages can be a property of a method/thing in isolation, with no comparison required.

This seems logically problematic to me. To exemplify: Method A is cheaper than almost all other methods, and so one might be tempted to claim that an advantage of A is that it is cheap, period. However in a situation where an even cheaper method "B" has already been mentioned, it seems foolish to still describe A as having an absolute advantage: cheapness.

## Research

I decided to check if dictionary definitions of an advantage indicate that it must be presented as an advantage of something over something else.

[Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advantage)

**Definition of advantage**
1: superiority of position or condition

```
Higher ground gave the enemy the advantage.
```

2: a factor or circumstance of benefit to its possessor

```
lacked the advantages of an education
```

3a: benefit, gain; especially : benefit resulting from some course of action

```
a mistake which turned out to our advantage
```

To me, these examples all have clear implied comparisons: e.g. the enemy has the advantage of higher ground, *over us, on our lower ground*

The advantages of an education are not detailed, but clearly are advantages *over people who lack an education*

## So...

Could anyone enlighten me, perhaps with examples of absolute advantages or disadvantages that do not imply a defined comparison, or otherwise are intrinsic attributes of an object/method/etc. in isolation?

Comment: You can certainly say that having something has an advantage over not having it. I think that applies to definition #2. So you are not comparing it to something else, but to the lack of that thing. I suspect that's what your teacher meant.

Comment: Much of human experience is about comparison. It is fundamental to our apprehension of that which is about us.

Comment: Without putting on my heaviest thinking cap, I'd say it's likely that there must always be at least 1 (and probably many) covert disadvantaged (with the broad sense less advantaged)  entity // entities // state/s. But it doesn't always need to be mentioned. BG has $30 billion but BH only has $28 billion. Who would talk about BH being less advantaged here?

Comment: Without putting on my heaviest thinking cap, I'd say it's likely that there must always be at least 1 (and probably many) covert disadvantaged (with the broad sense less advantaged)  entity // entities // state/s. But it doesn't always need to be mentioned. BG has $30 billion but BH only has $28 billion. Who would talk about BH being less advantaged here? Essentially, 'good points' is a synonym for 'advantages' in one of its senses, and this too involves comparison/contrast, often covert.